# Correct usage of openMP with Fortran Do Loops

Tags: loops, fortran, openmp

I am a beginner in coding Fortran and still in the main learning process. 
I wrote a programm for FE Simulation in Fortran which works. But the performance is still too slow. 
Therefore I first implemented sparse matrices, which sped up the code nicely. But it is still not fast enough.
This is why I thought using openMP und parallelize parts of the code would be really helpful.
But when I tried to implement the commands of openMP, either the code worked slower as before (I assume too much overhead) or it didn't execute correctly anymore.

Before the upcoming part of the code, there is one do loop which is for the time stepping.
Variable nE is quite high, lets say up to 50K or more. This loop is necessary to be computed for every time step. 
And it is the part of the code I want to parallelize:

```
!$omp parallel
!$omp do private(v, b, N_loc, c, n, vertices, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, etc...)
   do v = 1, nE
    do b = 1, 4
      N_loc(1,b) = umesh_elt(v,b)  !Extracting node numbers
      c(1,b) = c_s(N_loc(1,b),1)   !Extracting values
      n(1,b) = n_s(N_loc(1,b),1)
      vertices(b,1) = umesh_co(N_loc(1,b),1) !Extracting coordinates
      vertices(b,2) = umesh_co(N_loc(1,b),2) !Extracting coordinates
     end do  



    a1 = 0.25*(-vertices(1,1)+vertices(2,1)+vertices(3,1)-vertices(4,1))
    a2 = 0.25*(-vertices(1,1)-vertices(2,1)+vertices(3,1)+vertices(4,1))
    a3 = 0.25*(+vertices(1,1)-vertices(2,1)+vertices(3,1)-vertices(4,1))
    b1 = 0.25*(-vertices(1,2)+vertices(2,2)+vertices(3,2)-vertices(4,2))
    b2 = 0.25*(-vertices(1,2)-vertices(2,2)+vertices(3,2)+vertices(4,2))
    b3 = 0.25*(+vertices(1,2)-vertices(2,2)+vertices(3,2)-vertices(4,2))


     do j = 1, nGauss
       J_c(1,1) = a1 + a3*QuadRuleX(j,2)
       J_c(1,2) = a2 + a3*QuadRuleX(j,1)
       J_c(2,1) = b1 + b3*QuadRuleX(j,2)
       J_c(2,2) = b2 + b3*QuadRuleX(j,1)

       J_det(j,1) = J_c(1,1)*J_c(2,2) - J_c(1,2)*J_c(2,1)
     end do

     do k = 1, 4
       y(k,1) = 0.0
       do z = 1, nGauss
          r = QuadRuleX(z,1)
          t = QuadRuleX(z,2)

          if (k == 1) then
             phi = 0.25*(r-1)*(t-1)
          else if (k == 2) then
             phi = -0.25*(r+1)*(t-1)
          else if (k == 3) then
             phi = 0.25*(r+1)*(t+1) 
          else if (k == 4) then
             phi = -0.25*(r-1)*(t+1)
          endif


          phi_1 = 0.25*(r-1)*(t-1)
          phi_2 = -0.25*(r+1)*(t-1)
          phi_3 = 0.25*(r+1)*(t+1)
          phi_4 = -0.25*(r-1)*(t+1)


          c_h = c(1,1)*phi_1+c(1,2)*phi_2+c(1,3)*phi_3+c(1,4)*phi_4 
          n_h = n(1,1)*phi_1+n(1,2)*phi_2+n(1,3)*phi_3+n(1,4)*phi_4
          y(k,1)=(phi*((((hi-1)*c_h+hi)/(2*(hi-1)*c_h+1))*n_h*    (2-n_h)-n_h))*J_det(z,1)*QuadRuleW(z,1)+y(k,1)
        end do
     end do

    S(z1,1) = y(1,1)+S(z1,1)
    S(z2,1) = y(2,1)+S(z2,1)
    S(z3,1) = y(3,1)+S(z3,1)
    S(z4,1) = y(4,1)+S(z4,1)

   end do

!$omp end do
!omp end parallel
```

After this snap of code, there is the end of the time step do loop and some if clauses to stop the simulation if something specific has happened.

I compile this with the option 
    ifort -mkl -openmp NAME.f90
When try to execeute it with 
    time ./a.out
the code is not working correctly, the program starts and stop without any error.

I assume I am doing something wrong basically, like I have not correctly understood how to setup those do loops with openMP correctly. Does anybody have any advice?

I appreciate any help, thanks a lot!
Arne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little too long for a comment, so I'll post it as an answer...

It's hard to tell what is global and what is local without the whole `PRIVATE()` statement...

At a first glance, though, only the lines `S(,1) = y(,1)+S(,1)` appear to be critical. Can you make sure that no two threads try to access the same `S(,1)` at the same time? From what I see `z1`--`z4` are set *outside* the loop - so my guess would be that they are identical for all threads and a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) occurs.

If they are meant to be the same, this smells like a [`reduction`](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION) operation. As a quick fix (just for debugging, don't use it unless you *really* require it) you could but that code block into a [`critical`](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#CRITICAL) section.

Comment: Thank you for your post. This lead me to my mistake in my code. I tidied up the code couple of days a go, and the declaration of z was the problem. Thank you very much!